# rvest how to get last page number

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Trying to get the last page number:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/de/wohnung-kaufen"
page <- read_html(url)
last_page_number <- page %>%
        html_nodes("#pageSelection > select > option") %>%
        html_text() %>%
        length()
```

The result is empty for some reason.

I can access the pages by this url, for example to get page #3:

```
https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/de/wohnung-kaufen?pagenumber=3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in the right direction but I think you have got wrong css selectors. Try :

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/de/wohnung-kaufen'
url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes('div.select-container select option') %>%
  html_text() %>%
  tail(1L)

#[1] "1650"
```

An alternative :

```
url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes('div.select-container select option') %>%
  magrittr::extract2(length(.)) %>%
  html_text()
```